# Extending a distribution over samples to a distribution over functions

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, notation

A gaussian process is a distribution over a function space, which can be parametrized as

\begin{align}
  x(\cdot) &\sim \mathrm{GP}(m(\cdot), K(\cdot,\cdot))\,.
 \end{align}

For simplicity, let's choose $x\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.
We can write the probability density of a finite set of samples of $x$ as

\begin{align}
  p(\{x(l) : l \in L\}; m, K)
   &\propto \exp{\left[
    -\frac{1}{2}
    \sum_{i\in L}
    \sum_{j\in L}
     \left(x(i) - m(i)\right)
     {K(i,j)}^{-1}
     \left(x(j) - m(j)\right)
   \right]}\,.
 \end{align}

(Apologies for any notational misuse here). Can this be extended to the probability density for the infinite set $x(\cdot)$? Is it valid to write

\begin{align}
  p(x(\cdot); m, K)
   &\propto \exp{\left[
    -\frac{1}{2}
    \sum_{i\in \mathbb{R}}
    \sum_{j\in \mathbb{R}}
     \left(x(i) - m(i)\right)
     {K(i,j)}^{-1}
     \left(x(j) - m(j)\right)
   \right]}\,.
 \end{align}

It feels incorrect to me to sum over the reals rather than integrate, but I have little intuition in this area.

Answer (score 9):

I think your notation is a little bit misleading. It is not really clear what $p(\cdots)$ is.

The definition of a gaussian process over $\mathbb{R}$ is fairly simple. All that is asked is that if you fix any finite times $t_1 < \ldots < t_n,$ then the vector $(X_{t_1}, \ldots,X_{t_n})$ is jointly gaussian.

Which, as you observe, amounts to giving a vector of means and a matrix of covariances.

Now if you look at the entire process it lives in a space of functions. You can choose many different spaces. The simplest space could be $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}.$ But you also need a *measurable space*. So you can choose for example the product Borel measurable space: $(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\otimes \mathbb{R}} ),$ where the latter is the smallest sigma-algebra w.r.t which all the projections are measurable.

Maybe you could think that this is all too formal and not really needed. But the sigma-algebra actually *restricts the collection of sets which you are allowed to measure,* and - surprisingly enough - solves the problems with the notation you use in the second formula.

There is a general result that allows you to build measures on the spaces of functions by starting from the finite-dimensional distributions - which is exactly what you are asking for! This is the [Kolmogorov Consistency Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem). It tells you that if you have all the finite-dimensional distribution you can build a measure (or - the same - a random variable $X$) on the space of functions with your given finite dimensional distributions.

And now we come to your infinite sum / infinite product. It is a general fact that only countable sums or countable products can be finite (i.e. converge). This means that if you have $\sum_{i \in \mathbb{R}} a_i = a \in \mathbb{R}$ you can desume that almost all coefficients (apart from a countable set) are zero. Similarly for an uncountable positive (for the sake of simplicity) product if $\Pi_{i \in \mathbb{R}} a_i = a \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$ you can desume that almost all $a$ are 1.

Now let us take the probability measure associated to $X,$ and compute what you have written in the uncorrelated case $K(i,j) = \delta(i,j)$: note probability densities make sense only when integrated! Take an uncountable number of Borel sets $A_t$ and we get:

$$P(X_t \in A_t) = P(X \in \times_{t \in \mathbb{R}} A_t) =  \prod\limits_{t \in \mathbb{R}}P(X_t \in A_t)$$

Now as you can see this is not well defined unless the probability is zero (not interesting for our purposes) or we take all but a countable number of $A_t$ equal to $\mathbb{R}.$

So the solution to your problem eventually is: true enough, your formula does not rigorously make sense. And *it is not possible to always make sense of it*. You can make sense of it when you integrate it against a set in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\otimes \mathbb{R}}$ - which is by far a **smaller set** than the power set of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}},$ for example because it contains only product sets where countably many elements at most can be nontrivial.